# LINQ Sub-selection

Tags: c#, linq, subquery

I'm a student, new to LINQ and we've been given an assignment to deal with LINQ queries.

My problem is I've been struggling the past days to figure out the correct way to perform this step: print the customers name that has "Milk" inside their orders.

```
Write a LINQ query to select all customers buying milk.
Print the Name of each customer in the query.
```

For the sake of time, here is the structure of the data so that you can understand it:

```
        Product milk    = new Product { Name = "Milk",    Price = 13.02m };
        Product butter  = new Product { Name = "Butter",  Price = 8.23m };
        Product bread   = new Product { Name = "Bread",   Price = 17.91m };
        Product cacao   = new Product { Name = "Cacao",   Price = 25.07m };
        Product juice   = new Product { Name = "Juice",   Price = 17.03m };

        Customer c1 = new Customer { Name = "x", City = "g", Orders = new Order[] {
               new Order { Quantity = 2, Product = milk     },
               new Order { Quantity = 1, Product = butter   },
               new Order { Quantity = 1, Product = bread    }
            }
        };

        Customer c2 = new Customer { Name = "y", City = "g", Orders = new Order[] {
                new Order { Quantity = 1, Product = cacao   },
                new Order { Quantity = 1, Product = bread   },
                new Order { Quantity = 2, Product = milk    },
                new Order { Quantity = 2, Product = butter  },
            }
        };

        Customer c3 = new Customer { Name = "z", City = "g",  Orders = new Order[] {
                new Order { Quantity = 3, Product = juice   }
            }
        };

        Customer[] customers = new Customer[] { c1, c2, c3 };
```

As an example of the syntax I'm using with LINQ here is a reference of working code:

```
        var QueryCustomerByCity = from cus in customers.AsEnumerable()
                                     where cus.City == "g"
                                     select cus;

        foreach (Customer c in QueryCustomerByCity)
            Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} lives in {1}", c.Name, c.City);
```

I'm really trying hard to understand what's happening, so if you can help me please explain me how you reached such conclusion :)

Thank you a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query of:

```
var QueryCustomerByCity = from cus in customers.AsEnumerable() //for each customer in customers 
                          where cus.City == "g" // where the Customer is from the City "g"
                          select cus; // select the customer
```

reads as "for each customer represented as `cus` in the `customers` array where the customers City is "g" then retain the customer". So, as a result you'll have a sequence of customers where their City is "g".

As for your task, you're after is this:

```
var result = from cus in customers // for each customer in customers                  
             where cus.Orders.Any(o => o.Product.Name == "Milk") // where the product name is "Milk"
             select cus; // select the customer
```

This essentially goes over the customers in the `customers` array and checks their orders and if there's any product which has the name "Milk" retains that specific customer.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understood the logic of this task :)

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ query is a pipeline:  Data flows in a stream, element by element, from one clause to the next.  FROM some data source you can get a flow of elements (e.g., via `AsEnumerable`).  From a flow of elements you can *filter* on some predicate (function on an element returning a boolean), keeping in the flow only those elements that the predicate accepts (returns true for) and throwing away the others.  The filter is called WHERE and the predicate is the rest of the WHERE clause, e.g., `WHERE cus.City == "G"`.  And also, from elements in the flow, you can select a single field, changing the flow from a flow of the (original) element to a flow of the field.  This is a SELECT, as in `SELECT g.City` where the flow would change from a stream of customers to a stream of strings (each of which was a city name).

From this (and the other LINQ clauses you can learn) you can construct whatever data pipeline you wish.  Specifically, one that returns a stream of customer names given that the customer has ordered milk.